# Testing child validators

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

This is what I have:

```
public class BusinessUnitIdValidator : AbstractValidator<string>
{
    public BusinessUnitIdValidator(IConfigSettings configSettings)
    {
        LovFile buidLovFile = configSettings.BuidLovFile;
        RuleFor(x => x).NotEmpty().WithMessage(ValidationResultConstants.BUSINESS_UNIT_ID_SHOULD_NOT_BE_NULL);

        When(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x),
            () =>
            {
                RuleFor(x => x).Must((buid) => IsValidBusinessUnitId(buidLovFile, buid)).WithMessage(ValidationResultConstants.INVALID_BUSINESS_UNIT_ID);
            });
    }
}

public class CreateCustomerRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateCustomerRequest>
{
    public CreateCustomerRequestValidator(IValidator<string> _businessUnitIdValidator)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.BusinessUnitId).SetValidator(_businessUnitIdValidator);
   }
}
```

When I'm testing this through the below snippet, I'm not getting the validation message that the _businessUnitIdValidator throws.

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldThrowErrorsWhenValidationFails()
{
    // Arrange
    // sets one entry in the validationFailures collection
    List<ValidationFailure> validationFailures = TestUtility.GetValidationFailures();
    ValidationResult validationResultMock = new ValidationResult(validationFailures);
    _businessUnitIdValidatorMock = new Mock<IValidator<string>>();
    _businessUnitIdValidatorMock.Setup(b => b.Validate(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(validationResultMock);
    validator = new CreateContactMethodsRequestValidator(_businessUnitIdValidatorMock.Object);

    CreateContactMethodsRequest model = new CreateContactMethodsRequest();
    var validationResult = validator.Validate(model);

    // Assert
    validationResult.IsValid.ShouldBeFalse();
    validator.ShouldHaveChildValidator(x => x.BusinessUnitId, typeof(IValidator<string>));
    validationResult.Errors.Count.ShouldBe(1);
}
```

Why am I not getting the error sent by the _businessUnitIdValidator? How do I get that message?

[image]

I'm using FluentValidation.AspNetCore Version="8.4.0".

Comment: What do you receive,  a screenshot of the object you receive would be helpful

Comment: You are not testing with the actual validator since you've mocked it. Try creating an actual instance of `BusinessUnitIdValidator`

Comment: @LennartStoop, sir, I've modified the behavior of the child validator so that when it gets called a validationresult object with one validationfailure gets returned. Shouldn't this work?

Comment: I see. From the code I can't say what `TestUtility` is returning. When you debug the test, is the `validationResultMock.IsValid` true or false after it has been setup?

Comment: @LennartStoop, I updated the comment in above the TestUtility line. It returns one entry in the validationFailures collection. The validationResultMock.IsValid is still false after the setup and after the test run. Good thought though... hadn't checked that earlier.